# Shell code to print file names and their sizes

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I need to make a shell command that lists all file names and their sizes in a directory. I wrote this:

```
ls -l | awk ' {print $9, $5} '
```

the problem is that with $9 it only prints the first word of the name of the file.
Any tips to make it print the whole name?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, parsing output of `ls` is an unportable and unreliable practice in general. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use `find`:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s\t%f\n"
```

The `%f` directive prints the filename with leading directories removed.  `%s` produces the file size in bytes.

For restricting the listing to the current directory, use `-maxdepth`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%s\t%f\n"
```

You could also use `stat`:

```
stat --printf "%s\t%n\n" *
```

Comment: +1. That said, if we're assuming GNU find, we could also assume GNU stat and use that.

Comment: ...also, better to put the size *before* the name if you're going to parse the output list. (Even better to both do that and put a NUL delimiter after each filename, to disambiguate filenames with newlines in their contents from separators indicating that a filename has ended).

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error: find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Comment: @user3612623, that means you're on a system without GNU find. Fortunately, the linked page covers that; see the section titled "getting metadata from a file".

Comment: ...or the complete FAQ entry on the subject: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I have a little question now. That command prints only the name and size of the files in a directory. How can I make it print the name and size of the folders in the directory too?

Comment: @user3612623 What do you mean by size of folders?  That needs to be computed, you could use `du`.